# Excel: take horizontal data from table, organize vertically in a different sheet, ignoring blanks

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have a table of vendor contact info organized like:

```
vendorname | address | city | state | zip | phone | fax | contactperson | phone | email
```

...and I want to select `vendorname` from a dropdown menu on a different sheet (got that part handled) which would then populate the contact info for that vendor in the cells below.

To make it trickier, I want it to ignore any blank columns from the table. For example, say there is no fax number for an entry in the table. I don't want it to put an empty cell between 'phone' and 'contactperson.'

Can this be accomplished just using formulas?

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use the `VLOOKUP()` function. This would be an example:

```
=VLOOKUP($B$3, Table1,2,FALSE)
```

Where $B$3 is the cell with the dropdown and Table1 is the table with contact data. Put this formula in the first cell to be filled in when an item is selected from the dropdown. In the other cells to be filled in, you simply need to increment the third parameter (the column index parameter; eg 2 in the sample above).

AFAIK, there is no way to skip blank columns with this method. You'll probably need VBA for that.

Comment: You could wrap it in an IF to check for blanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be achieved only with formulas:

### Finding labels (column A):

`=IFERROR(INDEX(Table1[#Headers],SMALL(IF(OFFSET(Table1[#Headers],MATCH($B$8,Table1[vendorname],0),0)="","",COLUMN(Table1[#Headers])),ROW()-ROW($A$7))),"")`

- `MATCH($B$8,Table1[vendorname],0)` finds the row which contains the selected contact
- `OFFSET(Table1[#Headers],MATCH(...),0)` gets the address of the selected row
- `IF(OFFSET(...)="","",COLUMN(Table1[#Headers]))` checks which columns of the selected item contains data (empty value for empty ones, column number for the others)
- `SMALL(IF(...),ROW()-ROW($A$7)` selects the next column to be used
- `INDEX(Table1[#Headers],SMALL(...))` gets the the title
- `=IFERROR(INDEX(...),"")` shows empty cell after displaying all data

### Finding data (column B):

`=IFERROR(INDEX(OFFSET(Table1[#Headers],MATCH($B$8,Table1[vendorname],0),0),SMALL(IF(OFFSET(Table1[#Headers],MATCH($B$8,Table1[vendorname],0),0)="","",COLUMN(Table1[#Headers])),ROW()-ROW($A$7))),"")`

The only difference from previous one is the first parameter of `INDEX()`, which is the same `OFFSET()` formula used within small to find data in the selected row instead in the title.

Both formulas are array formulas, so you need to enter them by <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

[image]